# Lock computer script with win+l only sending l in AHK 2.0

Tags: autohotkey

I'm writing a script that locks my computer when I press F4. However, running my script below sends `"l"` (quotes and all), contrary to the documentation (https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Send.htm) that says:

> `Send "#e"` holds down Win and then presses E

---

***Here's my script:***

```
F4:: Lock()

Lock(){
  Send "#l"
}
```

***Here's what I've tried:***

- `Send #l` ==> `l`
- `Send {Lwin down}l{Lwin up}` ==> `l`

Answer (score 1):

WIN + L is  protected by Windows and cannot be send or be overridden.

The only way to lock the machine is to temporally [disable the Windows lock feature](https://www.howtogeek.com/801/disableenable-lock-workstation-functionality-windows-l/) via the registry and use DllCall("LockWorkstation"):

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

F4:: Lock()

Lock() {
    RegWrite 0, "REG_DWORD", "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System","DisableLockWorkstation" ; disable the Windows lock feature
    DllCall("LockWorkStation")
    Sleep(1000)
    RegWrite 1, "REG_DWORD", "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System","DisableLockWorkstation" ; reenable the Windows lock feature
}
```